# Summarizing list of pairwise statistical tests

Tags: r, statistics, permutation

**Intro**

After performing an ANOVA, we often perform a series of pairwise comparisons. When the number of groups is relatively large, the number of pairwise comparison becomes very big (it is its [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)). On graphs, it is common to indicate groups that are not significantly different by marking them with the same letter and it would therefore be handy to have a function that would produce these letters.

**Goal**

I am trying to build a function in `R` that would take in *input*:

- the output of `TukeyHSD(aov(y~x))`
- the alpha value

.. and would *output*:

- a list of character string that would indicate which groups are significantly different and which groups are not.

**Example**

```
set.seed(10)
d = data.frame(
    y=c(rnorm(100,10),rnorm(100,10),rnorm(100,8.5),rnorm(100,8)),
    x=rep(c("High","MidHigh", "MidLow","Low"), each=100)
)

z=TukeyHSD(aov(y~x,data=d))
z
  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = y ~ x, data = d)

$x
                      diff         lwr        upr     p adj
Low-High       -1.66461230 -2.02288676 -1.3063378 0.0000000
MidHigh-High    0.04158636 -0.31668810  0.3998608 0.9906564
MidLow-High    -1.33469921 -1.69297367 -0.9764247 0.0000000
MidHigh-Low     1.70619866  1.34792420  2.0644731 0.0000000
MidLow-Low      0.32991309 -0.02836138  0.6881876 0.0834543
MidLow-MidHigh -1.37628557 -1.73456004 -1.0180111 0.0000000
```

And here is what the function `fun` would do

```
fun(Tukey=z, alpha=0.05)
High MidHigh  MidLow     Low 
"A"     "A"     "B"     "B" 

fun(Tukey=z, alpha=0.1)
High MidHigh  MidLow     Low 
"A"     "A"     "B"     "C"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [multcompView](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcompView/index.html) package.

```
library(multcompView)
multcompLetters(z$x[,4])
##    Low MidHigh  MidLow    High 
##    "a"     "b"     "a"     "b"
```